# When i invoke the function inside the object ,gives two outputs one is what i consoled the other is undefine?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This  example show two output,  first output is name because i invoke test function (this.name), second  undefine ,why undefine ?

```js
let person = {
  name: "shubham",
  age: 25,
  test: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
console.log(person.test());
```

Output :
shubham,
undefine

Comment: Because the return value of `person.test()`, which you are logging to console, _is_ undefined.

Comment: Because the method test is returning anything, that's why you got undefined in the log.

Comment: The test function returns undefined, this is why output is shubham, undefined

Answer (score 0):

Here are provided two examples that can be used to get the desired output
while using the console and calling the function if function doesn't return any value it gives undefined.

```js
let person={
    name:"shubham",
    age:25,
    test:function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
person.test();


let person1={
    name:"shubham",
    age:25,
    test:function(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
console.log(person1.test());
```

Answer (score 0):

The undefined is for the first `console.log(person1.test())`. You are not returning any values from the test function. So it gets `undefined` as a return value after logging shubham.